# What's the reason behind the name Market in Control.Lens?

Tags: haskell, terminology, haskell-lens, lenses

[Edward Kmett's optics library; Control.Lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1) defines a large number of types.

Most of these have relatively self explanatory names, like [Traversal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html) and [Fold](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html).

It also defines some types with less obvious names, like [Bazaar](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Internal-Bazaar.html)

From the Bazaar page:

> a.k.a. indexed Cartesian store comonad, indexed Kleene store comonad, or an indexed FunList.

...

> Mnemonically, a Bazaar holds many stores and you can easily add more.

I can't figure out the reasoning behind the name of the type [Market](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Internal-Prism.html). 
I assume that this is somehow also related to store monads/comonads?
Is this correct?

Comment: A `Market` appears to be nothing more than a concrete representation of a `Prism` with its type arguments in an order convenient for `APrism`. A `Bazaar` is different, and I really don't know how it relates to `Store`.

Comment: For `Bazaar`, try looking at https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/cellular-automata — it gives a very brief overview near the beginning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not privvy to the true history, but I suspect the following. Let's line up the types this way:

```
Market' a s t: Market (a -> t) (s -> Either t a)
Store   a   t: Store  (a -> t)                a
```

So: a `Market a s t` is a bit like a collection of `Store a t`s indexed by `s`. Indeed, if you choose a particular `s`, then your `Market' a s t` becomes one of these two things:

1. The `s -> Either t a` returns a thing tagged by `Right`, so you have an `a -> t` and an `a`. This is exactly the same as a `Store a t`.
2. The `s -> Either t a` returns a thing tagged by `Left`. You have gotten yourself most of the way to a store: you have an `a -> t`, but instead of having a particular index `a` that function can be applied to, you have your hands directly on the `t` that would result. (N.B. I don't see any reason to believe that the `t` is necessarily in the codomain of the `a -> t`. I'm just giving an intuition for the name, not behavioral laws.)

I think it's okay: real-world markets often have things that are similar to but not quite exactly stores in them, too. =)